# Print second folder name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python code that sorts the folders inside a folder.
However, I want to print the name of the second folder and not all of them.
Any suggestions?

```
for root,dirs,files in os.walk("C:\\Folder testing"):
   for dirname in sorted(dirs, key=int, reverse=True):
     print(dirs)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? the second folder from where? As I can see you'll have to make a list of all the folders and just print afterwards.

Comment: Exactly.
I have the folder "Folder testing" and I want to print the name of the just one (in this case, the second one) inside it, instead of all the folders

Comment: If you want to print only one folder, then ¿why are you using os.walk?

Comment: Because first I want to organize them in a numeric order. That is why there is a sorted.

Comment: Ok, then just make a list with your folders, then sort the list, and then print the folder you want.

Comment: That is why I posted this. I have it organized. Just don't know how to print the name of one in specific.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97423/discussion-between-tglaria-and-user3329074).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use os.walk for printing just one folder.
I'd rather make a list of all the folders, and then select the one I want:

```
some_path = "C:\\Folder testing"
dirs = [f for f in os.listdir(some_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(some_path, f))]
dirs_sorted = sorted(dirs, key=int, reverse=True)
try: 
    print dirs_sorted[1]
except IndexError:
    print "Folder doesn't exist"
```

Beware that your sorting method requires that the folders names are numbers only.

Comment: Does not work. Gives error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Because that dir is empty.

Comment: The dir is not empty. I tried to print the list before the try cycle and it returns empty. (and yes, is supposed to be numbers only)